# cannot uninstall/install any software because of intellij Idea

Tags: apt, package-management, uninstall, intellij

Whenever I am installing/uninstalling any software it pops with errors:

[image: error snapshot]

Comment: Please copy ans paste the test from the terminal into the post...

Comment: Please try this `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what’s too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's an outdated, half-installed package on your system that can't be fully installed because its data was corrupted. Please remove it and try again:

```
sudo apt-get remove -f intellij-community-idea
```

Comment: As you’ve never accepted an answer before: if this answers your question, don’t forget to click the grey ☑ under the number at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means “yes, this answer is valid”!